# styled components extension is not Working in new update of Vs-code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I've updated vscode to 1.64, the styled-components extension is not suggesting anything. It was working correctly before this new update. is there any solution for that?

I am using react with typescript.

Comment: Check when was the last time extension was updated...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in update of styled-component extension's new version

Answer (score 0):

here same problem, looks like this update broken the extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yeah I've fixed it using vscode beta version.